# Change class using jQuery in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, class, google-chrome

I try to change a button class when i click it, from jQuery. I use .removeClass and .addClass 
but in Chrome and IE 9 my image is not displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#myButton').click(
            function () {
             $('#myButton').removeClass('forgetPass').addClass('forgetPassoff');
        });
    });
</script>

.forgetPass
{
    background-image:url("http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button.png");
    border: 0px;
    width: 89px;
    height: 21px;
}

.forgetPassoff
{
    background-image:url("http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button_off.png");
    border: 0px;
    width: 89px;
    height: 21px;
}

<input type="submit" value="" class="forgetPass" id="myButton" />
```

I use jQuery 1.6.2.

This is what i get instead of images:[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Got some HTML and CSS to show too?

Comment: That code will work fine i have used that pattern many times for switching classes, if it doesn't do what you expect then it is probably a problem with the CSS rather than the jQuery.

Comment: Hmmm... if the classes have background images on it, the page may have to load those or maybe not be able to load them.  I'm wondering a few things... if you can use show() and hide() instead or if on page load, you had both classes already assigned and then you switched them immediately.

Comment: But why Chrome is not able to load them and FireFox can? In FF works ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narnian solution solved my problem: "I'm wondering a few things... if you can use show() and hide() instead or if on page load, you had both classes already assigned and then you switched them immediately."

> HTML Code

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="forgetPass" id="myButton" />
<input type="button" value="" class="forgetPassoff" id="myButtonOff" />
```

> jQuery Code

```
 $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#myButton').click(
            function () {
                $('#myButton').hide();
                $('#myButtonOff').show();
            });
    });
```

> CSS Code

```
.forgetPass
{
  background-image:url("http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button.png");
  border: 0px;
  width: 89px;
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.forgetPassoff
{
  background-image:url("http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button_off.png");
  border: 0px;
  width: 89px;
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Too bad narnian didn't post this as an answer.  Please provide as much detail as possible to your answer and mark it as accepted.  You should not be asking follow-up questions within an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

You need the click method to do the operation.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('forgetPass').addClass('forgetPassoff'); 
});
```

Further more...this remove/add class logic must be working. Maybe the problem lies in your CSS or somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Apart from `$(this)` vs `$('#myButton')` your code is not different from Andrei’s?

Comment: True, my point is (besides that in his example the click code misses) that it should work as is and that the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: well first time was only this code $('#myButton').removeClass('forgetPass').addClass('forgetPassoff'); without the $('#myButton').click(function(){ part....

Answer (score 1):

Add lines below that pre-load the CSS background images...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        (new Image()).src = 'http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button.png';
        (new Image()).src = 'http://login.mywai.de/DCILogin/Images/Send_Button_off.png';

        $('#myButton').click(function () {
             $('#myButton').removeClass('forgetPass').addClass('forgetPassoff');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it was **not** working in Chrome before; so this fixed that.  And simply adding those two lines would not break anything in the previously working browsers.  Try putting them inside the `document.ready` - see updated answer.